# Zend Framework 2 - ZFCUser module installation

Tags: php, authentication, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, zfcuser

I need an authentication module for my `ZF2` project.

ZFCUser seems to be good and I installed it sucessfully. But now I'm a bit lost due to the lack of any further documentation (or I just don't know where to look for it).

**1) I want to include [ZFCUser-DoctrineORM](https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcUserDoctrineORM) but the readme says basically the name of the module and that's it. What do I have to do to get this working?**

After trying for some time I found the login page under the URL `/user/` and a [code snippet](https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcUser/wiki/How-to-embed-the-login-form-on-another-page) which shows how to include the form on another page.

**2) But how do I eg make login required for all my other pages or modules?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Question 1**

Alright, figured it out now... it's actually pretty easy!

*composer.json*

```
"zf-commons/zfc-user-doctrine-orm": "dev-master"
```

Run

```
php composer.phar update
```

Add app under *application.config*

```
'ZfcUserDoctrineORM'
```

Run `Doctrine CLI`

```
doctrine-module orm:schema-tool:update --force
```

**Question 2**

Here are the options for [checking the login state](https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcUser/wiki/How-to-check-if-the-user-is-logged-in).

Answer (score 1):

Here is wiki for ZfcUser : https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcUser/wiki

also you can look here if u already have not https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcUser

Edit your composer.json's require section add

```
"require": {
    "zf-commons/zfc-base": "dev-master",
    "zf-commons/zfc-user": "dev-master",
    "doctrine/doctrine-orm-module": "dev-master"
}
```

Now tell composer to download by running the command:

```
$ php composer.phar update
```

Comment: to my first question, the wiki says nothing and your second link says: `Coming soon...` would be great if you could post a quick guide how to install it... and to my second question: interpreting the wiki, I guess you just have to add this auth check in every action?

Comment: i think `ZFCUser-DoctrineORM` is now installed (you left the important line out) with `"zf-commons/zfc-user-doctrine-orm": "dev-master"`. but how do i set it up?